# How to structure a multi-file Python app

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7, I have a large class object, in a single file, I want to break into multiple files by groups or related functions.  For example, I have "class API(object)", and I would like to have separate Python files for all user methods (add user, update user, delete user) and a separate Python file for all order methods (create order, update order, delete order).  But this separation should not be known to the end-user, such as:

```
z = test.api()                __init__.py
z.adduser(jeff)               user.py
z.createOrder(65, "jeff")     orders.py
z.showOpenOrders("jeff")      orders.py
z.completeOrder()             orders.py
z.emailUser("Jeff")           email.py
```

I have been searching for "extending python class", but I don't believe I am searching using the right term.  Please help.

Comment: You want to have *one class* defined over *multiple files*? This sounds like *you should [consider refactoring your class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)*.

Comment: Is the term to create child classes that extend a parent class?  Today this is one giant class in one large file.  Now that everything is working, I want to break things into separate files.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead create specialized classes (`Users`, `Orders`) where instances are created in `API.__init__` (if necessary they could hold a reference to the `API` instance). The specialized instances can then be retrieved through member attributes or properties of the `API` instance.

Calls to them would then look like:

```
z = test.api()
z.users.add(jeff)
z.orders.create(65, "jeff")
z.orders.showOpen("jeff")
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend against this approach.  It's typical in python to keep  the definition of class in one file.  Another answer discusses options for splitting your API across multiple classes, and if that works for your application that may be a great option.  However, what you propose is possible in Python and so I'll describe how to do it.

In a.py:

```
class A:

# some methods go here
```

in b.py:
    import a
    def extra_a_method(self, arg1):
        # method body
    a.A.extra_a_method = extra_a_method
    del extra_a_method

So, we create a function and add it into the A class.  we had to create the function in some scope, and so to keep that scope clean, we delete the function from that scope.
You cannot do `def A.new_a_method` for syntactic reasons.
I know this will mostly work in Python3, but haven't analyzed it for Python2.
There are some catches:

- b must be imported before the method appears in `A`; this is a big deal
- If `A` has a nontrivial metaclass, the handling of the extra methods will be different from the handling of the methods in the original class.  As an example, I think SQLAlchemy would get this sort of addition right, but other frameworks might not.

There's an alternative that can work sometimes if you know all the things that `A` should contain from the beginning

In a.py:

```
import a_extra_1, a_extra_2

class A(a_extra_1.AExtra1, a_extra_2.AExtra2):

    # methods can also go here
```

Here, we're treating the additional methods as mixins to `A`.  Generally, you'd want to have  the mixins added after any classes for inheritance.
This approach also has some drawbacks:

- If you are not careful it can lead to circular imports
- You have to know all the methods you need for `A` ahead of time
- All the code gets imported at once (this is a feature too)

There can also  be issues with nontrivial metaclasses in this approach, although if the framework supports inheritance, this is likely to work.